# Race conditions with file loading

Tags: node.js, race-condition

If I use node via the command line and require the module, use the `load` function and then the `get` function it returns the expected string from the config file.

```
➜  cz  node
> var config = require('./index.js');
undefined
> config.load('/Users/xo/code/cz/config.json');
undefined
> config.get()
{ username: 'xo' }
> config.get('username')
'xo'
```

If I try the same thing via a file I get `undefined` returned instead of `{ username: xo }`.

```
➜  cz  node test.js
undefined
```

This is the `test.js` file.

```
var config = require('./index.js');
config.load('./config.json');
console.log(config.get('username'));
```

This is my module.

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
let config = {};

module.exports = {
    load: function(path) {
        fs.readFile(path, function(err, data) {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var prop in data){
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    config[prop] = data[prop];
                }
            }
        });
    },
    get: function(prop){
        if(prop){
            return config[prop];
        } else {
            return config;
        }
    },
    set: function(prop, value) {
        config[prop] = value;
        return config[prop];
    }
};
```

This is the `config.json` file.

```
{
    "username": "xo"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `load` function is asynchronous.  That means it starts the operation and returns immediately and then the actual operation finishes some time later.  You will need to change the interface to your `load` function so that the caller can know when it is done and when it then safe to user other operations.

There are many possible designs here.  One way is like this:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
let config = {};

module.exports = {
    load: function(path, callback) {
        fs.readFile(path, function(err, data) {
            if (err) { return callback(err);}
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var prop in data){
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    config[prop] = data[prop];
                }
            }
            // communicate that all data is now loaded
            callback(null);
        });
    },
    get: function(prop){
        if(prop){
            return config[prop];
        } else {
            return config;
        }
    },
    set: function(prop, value) {
        config[prop] = value;
        return config[prop];
    }
};
```

Then, your caller could know when the load operation was done:

```
var config = require('./index.js');
config.load('./config.json', function(err) {
    // in here, we know that the config data is done loading
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(config.get('username'));
    }
});
```

Also, please realize that it does you no good to do a `throw err` inside an async callback.  That exception just goes back into the bowels of the `fs.readFile()` function and none of your code ever sees that exception.  That's why I used a callback and the node.js callback calling convention to communicate an error.

Also, you may want to realize that the `require()` function (if given a filename that ends with `.json`) will automatically parse the JSON for you and it will load it synchronously (it is meant for use at startup when loading configuration information).

So, you could also do:

```
let config = require('/Users/xo/code/cz/config.json');
```

`require()` will load the data synchronously (similar to `fs.readFileSync()`) so you don't have to use the callback scheme.

---

If your code is such that the config could be just loaded synchronously at startup, then you could just do this:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(path) {
   let config = require(path);
   return {
        get: function(prop) {
            if (prop) {
                return config[prop];
            } else {
                return config;
            }
         },
         set: function(prop, value) {
              config[prop] = value;
              return config[prop];
         }
     }
}
```

And, then the use of it would look like this:

```
var config = require('./index.js')('./config.json');
console.log(config.get('username'));
```

---

You could also just simplify your `load()` method like this:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
let config = {};

module.exports = {
    load: function(path) {
        Object.assign(config, require(path));
    },
    get: function(prop){
        if(prop){
            return config[prop];
        } else {
            return config;
        }
    },
    set: function(prop, value) {
        config[prop] = value;
        return config[prop];
    }
};
```

Comment: Added second implementation that uses `require()` to load the JSON file.

Comment: Since the callback returns null for the first one would it be possible to omit the callback in the config.load line so it can be used simply as `config.load('./config.json');` like I was doing before?

The main reason I didn't just load the JSON file was I'm planning on adding other methods to the module so I needed some logic that I can just require instead of doing all of the logic in my actual application.

Comment: @XO - No.  Please read my answer again as it is very important that you understand.  The callback tells the code that follows when the `.load()` has completed so the code that follows knows when it can do `.get()` or other methods.  Without the callback, the code will never know when it's allowed to do those other methods.  The second option uses synchronous IO so the callback is not needed.  Callbacks must nearly always be used when doing async IO like `fs.readFile()`.

Comment: Okay, this solves the question but I actually found another way by just changing the load function to use `fs.readFileSync`.

Comment: @XO - Synchronous file operations should only ever be used at server startup time.  After that, synchronous file operations ruin the scalability and performance of a node.js server.  If `.load()` is only ever called at startup, then it is OK to use `fs.readFileSync()`, otherwise, it's a bad thing.  That concept is very important for you to understand in node.js development.

Comment: I'm not new to nodejs, just new to using file functions. You would only ever load a config file at the start so that's fine that everything will wait for it to finish as there's no reason to continue loading the application if you don't have any configuration details.

Comment: @XO - Then why not just use `require()` to load it (as in my second option) since it loads it synchronously and parses it for you.  Replace your nine lines of code in `.load()` with one line of code.

Comment: I want the load command separate from the require so that won't work.

Comment: @XO - Apparently you don't yet understand how you could use `require()` to simplify your `.load()` method.  See the last code block I added to my answer.  `require()` will read the file and parse it for you.  You don't need to write code to do that.

Comment: `config = require(path);` this doesn't work if I want to load objects into the config object after others are already in it. This replaces config with the results from the path. I'd rather just use what I have.

Comment: @XO - That requirement (which I did not know was a requirement) has nothing to do with using `require()`.  See my latest edit to the last code block.  The point is that you don't have to read and parse your own JSON.  `require()` will do that for you, regardless of what you want to do with the results.